# How can i insert if statement to variable in php

Tags: php, dynamic

I'm trying to make a dynamic tab with PHP. please can someone help me out just need to filter where the category parent = 0.

```
$parent_category_html.= '<span class="'.$current_tab.'"><a id="tab-'
. $category['id'].'-link" href="#tab-'.$category['id']
. '" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-1" class="tab-link">'
. **$category['title'] is it possible to put an if statement here to filter the title where parent = 0**
. '</a>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you're trying to do, please?

Comment: What do you mean by "insert if statement to variable" or by "filter the title"?

Comment: what I'm trying to do is to insert if statement. in category title to filter where parent = 0 i think like this if($parent = 0){ $category['title'] }

Comment: @David both insert to filter

Comment: @D3vm4d: Do you mean that you only want to include the `$category['title']` value in the resulting string if `$parent == 0`?

Comment: @David yes sir if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments on the question, it sounds like what you're asking is:

> How can I conditionally include a value in my string?

For that you'd use the [ternary conditional operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).  The operation itself would look like this:

```
$parent == 0 ? $category['title'] : ''
```

It essentially means:

> If $parent equals 0, $category['title'], else empty string

The whole operation resolves to the resulting value, so you can wrap the whole operation in parentheses and drop it anywhere you would a variable.  So something like this:

```
$parent_category_html.= 'your various HTML code...'
  . ($parent == 0 ? $category['title'] : '')
  . 'the rest of your HTML code...';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add if statement before:

```
if (statement)
   $parent_category_html .= '...';
```

or try to use ternary operator
 `$parent_category_html .= "<div>" . ($condition ? 'output if true' : 'output if false') . "</div>";`

```
    $parent_category_html.= '<span class="'.$current_tab.'"><a id="tab-' . $category['id'].'-link" href="#tab-'.$category['id'] . '" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-1" class="tab-link">'; 
    
    if ($pareent_id ==0) { 
        $parent_category_html.= '...'; 
    } 

    $parent_category_html.= '</a>';
```

Comment: code **' . $category['title'] . '** need to insert there  an if statement to filter.  parent category = 0